# Как правильно реализовать ссылки "поделиться" социальных сетей

Tags: javascript, html, css, вконтакте, facebook

Я реализовал это через API каждой соц сети. По гайду оф документаций vk.com , facebook.com , twitter . Все работает хорошо и отображается тоже, но

1. Именно таких иконок не было и пришлось костылить(скрывать слово поделиться)
2. Подгрузка скприптов занимает пару секунд(т.е) если обновить страницу иконки в модалке появятся через секунду
3. Не могу через css достучаться до "внутренностей iframe"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "внутренностей iframe" - это явно вы не по API делаете )) вы наверно просто вставили виджет. По API вы можете сделать как вам нужно т.е на свои изображения и т.д

Comment: Так, уже какое-то просветление. Да , именно так. Я вставляю все виджетами. Сейчас нашел библиотеку https://ellisonleao.github.io/sharer.js/ и буду ее использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать виджеты каждой из социальных сетей не лучшее решение. Есть несколько готовых библиотек

1. https://ellisonleao.github.io/sharer.js/
2. https://github.com/delfimov/JS-Share

Comment: лайк Вам за библиотеки - пополнил свой инструментарий

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу счётчика "поделились", по этому смысл париться, запилить ссылки и всё.

```css
.repost a {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="repost">
  <a href="https://vk.com/share.php?url=https://ru.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Репост в VK</a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://ru.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Репост в Facebook</a>
  <a href="https://connect.ok.ru/offer?url=https://ru.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Репост в Одноклассники</a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://ru.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Репост в Twetter</a>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://ru.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Репост в Google Plus</a>
</div>
```